# Switching branches safely in git

Tags: git

I'm on the master branch, and want to work on a new feature so I do:

```
git checkout -b new_feature
```

Now I am coding, doing a git status shows the files modified.

If I try and move to the master branch it says I can't b/c of the files that were updated.

ok so i'll add them:

```
git add -A
```

now if I try and jump to the master branch, it seems to be wanted to merge???

```
git checkout master
```

What I want to know how to do is:

1. while in another branch, I want to stop what I am doing and move to the master branch, not merging anything yet, I just want to stop working on the new feature branch and go back to master.

Comment: Can you give the specific message you see when you try to jump to the master branch?

Comment: no I didn't commit after add.

Comment: msg is:  "error Entry '....' would be overwritten by merge. cannot merge"    I'm confused as I didn't ask it to merge!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got two choices (at least).  A "work in progress" commit, or the stash.

A "work in progress" commit is just that: it's a commit in a branch that represents unfinished work:

```
$ git commit -am'WIP (description here)'
$ git checkout master
```

Later, when you come back to your branch, you can continue working and committing:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
# do work
$ git commit -am'Finish WIP (description here)'
```

When done, you can merge your "WIP" commits together, if you want, into coherent commits with no evidence that you committed partial work:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2    # See instructions for rebase -i elsewhere
```

Or, you can use the stash:

```
$ git add .
$ git stash save 'WIP (descriptino here)'
$ git checkout master
```

Later, when you get back to your branch:

```
$ git checkout my_branch
$ git stash pop
```

You'll be right where you left off.

Comment: that's perfect, I'll take the stash!

Comment: @Blankman: Remember that when you use the stash, Git doesn't remember which branch it applied to (unless you put that in the stash description) and doesn't remind you to reapply it when you go back to the `new_feature` branch. Using a commit is often better because you've told Git what you intend to do with those changes.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you forget to `commit` the changes you `add` to the index.

```
git add <something>
git commit
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing git add -A you're just adding your changes to the index - that is, you're telling git that those changes are the ones you will commit once you do git commit. You actually didn't commit anything tho, so when you try to checkout something else git warns you because you would lose your index.
git commit -m "Your commit message" will add the indexed changes into the tree on top of new_feature and remove them from the index, so you're free to switch branch right after.

Git stash is another option, but depending on how likely your changes on new_features are to generate conflicts, you might prefer to make a commit (you can then reset --mixed HEAD~1 in order to go up by one commit without changing your working copy).